# Cash register - My code should be working because it is returning what freecodecamp is asking for but for some reason it says my code is wrong

Tags: javascript

I need some help. I am doing the bonfire on freecodecamp "Cash Register". My code should be working because it is returning what freecodecamp is asking for but for some reason it says my code is wrong, even though both answers are the same. Can someone look at my code and let me know what is wrong?

```
      let cashValue = [
        {name:"ONE HUNDRED", value:100},
        {name:"TWENTY", value:20},
        {name:"TEN", value:10},
        {name:"FIVE", value:5},
        {name:"DOLLAR", value:1},
        {name:"QUARTER", value:0.25},
        {name:"DIME", value:0.1},
        {name:"NICKEL", value:0.05},
        {name:"PENNY", value:0.01}
       ]
     function checkCashRegister(price, cash, cid) {
       var change = cash -price;
       console.log(change);
       let total = parseFloat(cid.reduce((acc,next)=>{return acc + 
       next[1]},0.0)).toFixed(2);
       let changeStatus = {status:"", change:[],};

       if(total<change){
         return {status: "INSUFFICIENT_FUNDS", change: []};
       } else if(total == change){
         return  {status: "CLOSED", change: cid};
       } else {
         cid = cid.reverse();
         cashValue.forEach((next,index)=>{

      if(change >= next.value){
         let currentValue = 0.0;
         while(change>=next.value && cid[index][1]>=next.value){
             currentValue += next.value;
             change -= next.value;
             change = Math.round(change * 100)/100;
             cid[index][1] -=next.value;
         }
         changeStatus.status = "OPEN";
         changeStatus.change.push([next.name,currentValue]);
       }
    });
   }        //console.log(change);

    if(change !== 0){
      changeStatus.status = "INSUFFICIENT_FUNDS";
      changeStatus.change = [];
    }
      return changeStatus;
    }

      checkCashRegister(3.26, 100, [["PENNY", 1.01], ["NICKEL", 2.05], 
     ["DIME", 3.1], ["QUARTER", 4.25], ["ONE", 90], ["FIVE", 55], 
     ["TEN", 20], ["TWENTY", 60], ["ONE HUNDRED", 100]]);
     // Should return {status: "OPEN", change: [["TWENTY", 60], ["TEN", 
    20], ["FIVE", 15], ["ONE", 1], ["QUARTER", 0.5], ["DIME", 0.2], ["PENNY", 0.04]]}
```

Comment: Your expected output contains `["ONE", 1]`, but the actual output has `["DOLLAR", 1]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah, your code is fine.  Here I copied it from my console log.

```
change 96.74

0: (2) ["TWENTY", 60]
1: (2) ["TEN", 20]
2: (2) ["FIVE", 15]
3: (2) ["DOLLAR", 1]
4: (2) ["QUARTER", 0.5]
5: (2) ["DIME", 0.2]
6: (2) ["PENNY", 0.04]
```

Try changing the variable name for singles from DOLLAR to ONE like Johnny said and you should pass...